# remove zoom hover effect in WordPress on Products

Tags: wordpress

I have an e-commerce website in wordpress, when I hover over a product on product page it zooms in, can someone tell me how to disable it

I have added this code but it doesnot works

```
function remove_image_zoom_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
} add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support' );
```

Comment: likely it is a feature of your template. they likely used CSS to do this. You will have to override the CSS that is responsible for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the image zoom feature on the product page in a WooCommerce store, you might need to use a different approach. The code you've provided is related to removing theme support for WooCommerce product gallery zoom, but it might not work for all themes.

Here's an alternative method that you can try:

```
// Remove WooCommerce product image zoom
remove_action('init', 'wc_gallery_image_zoom_init');
```

Add this code to your theme's functions.php file. This code removes the action that initializes the WooCommerce product image zoom functionality.

Please note that the effectiveness of this code can depend on the specific theme and how it handles WooCommerce features. If the above code doesn't work, you may need to explore your theme's documentation or settings to see if there's an option to disable image zoom. Alternatively, you can contact the theme's support for assistance.

Remember to clear your browser cache or use an incognito window to test the changes after adding the code.